# Axios blocked by CORS but HTMLParser isn't? (Web Browser Scraper)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I have a Python web scraper using the HTMLParser module. The website it scraps is http://consulta.siiau.udg.mx/wco/sspseca.consulta_oferta?ciclop=202120&cup=D&mostrarp=100000&ordenp=2

Now I need to do the same but **web browser based** using javascript, so I tried fetching the raw HTML using axios but I keep getting *'Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy'*.

What I have tried is

```
axios.post('http://consulta.siiau.udg.mx/wco/sspseca.consulta_oferta', {
        ciclop: '202120',
        cup: 'D',
        mostrarp: 10000,
        ordennp: 2,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
```

And

```
axios.get('http://consulta.siiau.udg.mx/wco/sspseca.consulta_oferta?ciclop=202120&cup=D&mostrarp=100000&ordenp=2',
        { crossdomain: true }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
```

I am aware that in javascript they normally use a headless browser like the one inside Puppeteer, but since this project is a website
I can't use Node.js modules.

Right now the solution I implemented is to have a server running a Flask API that handles the html fetching and then sends it back to the client for processing, but it would be a relieve for my server performance if the client could do this on his side.

Comment: If you getting denied by cors then is in your api were you need to allow external cors

Comment: CORS is enforced by the browsers. Python is not a browser.

Comment: @Eloi No, my API is just a workaround for fetching the html data from consulta.siiau.udg.mx. There is not a CORS problem between the client and my API nor my API and consulta.siiau.udg.mx.

Comment: @tevemadar I see, but why Puppeteer does not get blocked by CORS if it uses a Headless Browser? I just tested it at https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Comment: Because Puppeteer doesn't run in the browser (like the JavaScript code here), it controls a browser. And the browser is browsing the given page. But now you have browser-based JavaScript, so the browser is browsing your page, and tries to get data from another site - and that's the "field" of CORS. A simple workaround is to co-host some server-side code with your page (Python, PHP, node, whatever), which proxies any external data your page needs. But it comes at the price of running active code on your server.

Comment: @tevemadar That's a better explanation, thank you. Guess I'll stick with my workaround then

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't use the fetch API or XMLHTTPRequest to access resources that aren't allowed by the browser's cross-origin policy.

For security reasons, browsers restrict HTTP requests initiated from scripts. A web application can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

You can use a headless browser (puppeteer) to access a web page, for example using:

```
 await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

This is equivalent to putting `http://example.com` in the browser bar and pressing ENTER.  Any scripts on that page are subject to the same cross-origin restrictions as before.  However, telling the browser to visit `http://example.com` isn't a cross-origin request in itself.